# Biblatex set specific citationstyle for \cite only

Tags: biblatex

I am using this in my `.tex` file:

```
%Bibliography
\usepackage[sorting=none,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{expose}
```

And it gives a `(author year)` output for `\parencite{reference}` and `author (year)` for `\cite{reference}`.
\parencite gives me what I want, but I'd like \cite to give me `[number]` as output with number = index number in references.

How can I accomplish that?

Further explanation:

I have the sections "Scientific Background and Motivation", "Related Work", "Literature" and "References".

An easy Example:

```
"Scientific Background and Motivation": ("Chocolate can be dangerous." as an indirect citation)
Chocolate can be dangerous.[1]

"Related Work":
The article (Willy Wonka et. al. 2022) has made a significant contribution to chocolate research.

"Literature":
The book from (Charlie et. al. 2023) is a good source for understanding the science behind chocolate poisoning.

"References" (automatically generated by using \printbibliography)
[1] Lonkas et. al. "The danger of chocolate".....
[2] Willy Wonka et. al. "The way to not dangerous chocolate"...
[3] Charlie et. al. "Why chocolate poisons people"...
```

Comment: you shouldn't use authoryear with an unsorted bibliography. How should the reader find the entry? Go through the whole list?

Comment: They can click on ```(author year)``` and instantly are at the right reference.

Comment: which means that your text can never be printed on paper. And why do you want two different cite styles? Use always numbers, and \textcite if you want also the author.

Comment: Usually it is a pretty bad idea to mix different styles (especially for the same bibliography). Is there any particular reason why you want author-year citations and numeric citations?

Comment: It's not needed to be printed on paper since it's supposed to be a 2-4 pages long exposé, with a small references list, before I'm allowed to begin my bachelor's thesis. I got told to use [index number] for direct and indirect citations and (author year) when mentioning books and articles in the sections "Related Work" and "Literature". The three lines ```
%Bibliography
\usepackage[sorting=none,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{expose}
```
are part of the exposés template.

Comment: Does that mean you have two different list of references/bibliographies at the end? (Do you have to use the template? If you have to use a certain format for your exposé and you got a template for that, maybe ask the person who gave you the template about implementing the desired style.)

Comment: No, everything's listed in one. It's like when you're using \parencite to mention a resource and \footcite (I'm not allowed to use footcite) for indirect citations. All resources will end up in ```\printbibliography```

Comment: But that will lead to complete carnage and confusion (at least how I currently understand it). Can you explain the exact requirements in more detail again in an edit to the question (so I can be sure I got it right)? Are you absolutely sure you have to use this style mixture?

Comment: @moewe I've added further explanation what it'd would look like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to mix an author-year style with a numeric style in this way. The author-year labels can't easily be resolved in a numeric bibliography (especially one that is sorted by appearance). Plus, I don't think the parenthetical citations make sense as shown in the question: The sentence should still scan if you ignore the parentheses, but in the example sentences the parenthetical citations are integral parts of the sentence structure.

I suggest you go for `style=numeric,` exclusively and then use

- `\autocite` (or `\parencite`) for "direct" citations and
- `\textcite` for "indirect" citations (making sure that the name is subject/object) in the sentence.

Your example would then become

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Scientific background}
Chocolate can be dangerous. \autocite{sigfridsson}

\section{Related work}
Recently \textcite{worman} has made a significant contribution to chocolate research.

\section{Literature}
The book by \textcite{nussbaum} is a good source for understanding the science behind chocolate poisoning.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Scientific background Chocolate can be dangerous. [1] 2 Related work Recently Worman [2] has made a significant contribution to chocolate research. 3 Literature The book by Nussbaum [3] is a good source for understanding the science behind chocolate poisoning.]